# ImageView selector does not work

Tags: android, selector

I am forming a tabhost like layout in my application with several ImageView. When I select on an item, the image will change. However, I tried to click on it, nothing happens! why???

activity_main.xml

```
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_tab_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/news"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_news_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_share_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_camera_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_status_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/others"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_others_selector"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

main_tab_news_selector.xml (the other selectors are just similar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_time"
        android:state_focused="true"
        />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add this to your ImageView

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: android:focusable="true" would allow the focus state color also

Answer (score 6):

Your drawable xml code should look like this

```
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed.png" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/select.png" />
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed.png" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal.png" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Why your not using Image button?

Comment: it only works as pressed, but how can I select it?? like selecting a tab??

Comment: use android:state_activated=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66178/discussion-between-amy-and-simon).

Comment: is item android:state_activated="false"

Answer (score 2):

Set the `focusableInTouchMode` to be true and listen to its `state_focus` in the selector.

It solves the problem :)

activity_main.xml

```
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_tab_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/news"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_news_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_share_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_camera_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_status_selector"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/others"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/main_tab_others_selector"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

the selectors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_time"
        android:state_focused="true"
        />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_time"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_airplane_mode_on" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

1. `ImageView` to `ImageButton`
2. `src` to `background`

`src` also works butt it show some space around the drawable.

Write `android:state_focused="true"` before `android:drawable="@drawable/ic"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the `onTouchListener` on the View. On the `onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)`, you have to return false.